# how do I change window size?

Tags: javascript, html, background, window, size

I'm trying to change the  size of my window onload. It doesn't seem to work.

Here is the setup:

```
<script>

var w=800;
var h=600;

function changeScreenSize(w,h)
 {
   window.resizeTo(w,h)
 }

</script>

<body onload="changeScreenSize(w,h)" style="background-image:url(Untitled.jpg)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is from php.org (somewhere) - works for windows DOM, Mac cracks.
Hide menubar and favs, percent (width,height) gets complicated:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/top-bottom-halves-layout/

```
    <script>
    function changeScreenSize(w,h)
    {
    window.resizeTo( w,h )
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeScreenSize(1200,260)">
```

http://ysdn2005-w11.wikispaces.com/Change+Browser+Window+Size+Upon+Loading
Yep, this page details method. Script above works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeScreenSize()
{
w=window.open('','', 'width=800,height=600');
w.focus();
}


<body onload="changeScreenSize()">
```